# Reading rows of CSV file into string

Tags: python, csv

I have a string of id's in numbers saved as CSVs

[image: enter link description here]

I want to convert each row in this csv file to be a string/list

```
mylist=[411211, 1234404, 5711427, 13600442, 13600641, 13601660, 13619537, 15302899 ...]
```

Then each numbers on this string will go through an API request and then spit out Names

Then I want to be able to store these names in csv again.

I know the code for converting numbers to names via API works because I tried to manually type in the numbers as lists in python and was able to print out names in python. But I'm having a trouble working with csv...

---

Converting into list worked.

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

with open('jfl42facebooknumberid.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    
    for row in reader:
        myid='. '.join(row)
        try:
            myfile=urllib2.urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ myid +"?fields=name")
            myjson=json.loads(myfile.read())
            print myjson["name"]
        except:
            print myid
```

But this prints me the results I want! I just need to figure out how to store into a csv.

Comment: Also in Python 2.x, http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I know I know sorry I was looking at it for the longest time but I kept getting weird results... sorry really new to python but the first part worked! I just have to store printed results as csv file...

Comment: I know why actually.. it was because I kept using rb when I had to use rU (I still don't get what the difference between the two is...)

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open . `rb` is for non-text files so not for CSV. `rU` handles newlines correctly even if the CSV file was written on a different OS, with a different newline convention, than the OS you are running Python on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[if you go to csv in docs python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), the example is:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

I think it is a great and simple example.